# AzureDevops - YAML pipeline - each expression with variable group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Trying to use an each expression with a variable group. In the variable group, I've define a variable with multiple values.
In the variable group  "vg.test" - I have the variable "environments": dev, qa, uat, prod

Trying to run a set of commands for all environments defined in the variable with each expression.

YAML file:

---

```
variables:
- group: vg.test

jobs:
  - ${{ each env in $(environments) }}:
    - job:
      displayName: 
      steps:
      - template: 
        parameters:
          server_name: 
          user_name: 
          password: 
          cleanup_period:
```

---

-- Pipeline Error --

**while parsing pipeline YAML:
Unrecognized value: '$'. Located at position within expression: $(environments).**

If I use each expression with parameters.environmments (as long as I define environemnts as parameter) - the pipeline is running properly.

Comment: `each` is compile time directive on azure devops. You could try to use the template expression for variable group, but I am not sure if this will work.  `${{ each env in variables.environments }}:` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: jobs:
  - ${{ each env in variables.environments }}: --->>Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
The pipeline must contain at least one job with no dependencies.